# Is there a alternative for WorkspaceApi in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, workspaceapi, navigationmixin.navigate

**Background & The Problem**

We have a custom grid lwc which i am using to display data from two different objects (EmailMessage & CustomObject). Now, I want to navigate the user to a new tab with Contact as Primary tab and Case as Sub-tab when they click on CaseNumber. I am able them to navigate to a new tab (Case) by using NavigationMixin.Navigate (code shown below) but not sure how to open it as a sub-tab without using workspaceapi since LWC doesn't support it yet.

```
handleGenericClick(){
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId: this.caseId,
                actionName: 'view'
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the only way to achieve this behaviour would be to wrap your component in an Aura wrapper and handle interaction with the workspace API there. The LWC component should bubble up an event to its Aura wrapper when the workspace API needs to be used.

Answer (score 3):

This is possible via this https://mtr-design.com/news/salesforce-mini-how-to-open-a-subtab-in-console-from-lightning-web-component (Solution #2)

I just tried it and using `internalapievent` as custom event the workspace api events works.

Example is only given for `openSubtab` but you can try and edit for other events too.

There is a new release in winter24 related to workspace api.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_workspaceAPI.htm&release=246&type=5

So it should be possible to use workspace api in LWC from Winter24.

Answer (score 3):

I can suggest one of the approaches that we adopted on our projects.

Wrapping into Aura might be tedious, so I suggest creating an Aura Utility bar component (you can also use hidden Utility Component) and communicate with it through Messaging Channel.

This way you can re-use the same logic anywhere in your Application or potentially in other projects.

**SAMPLE CODE:**

```
//LWC
import globalApiChannel from "@salesforce/messageChannel/globalApiChannel__c";

action() {
    publish(this.msgContext, globalApiChannel, {
      action: 'open-subtab',
      params: {
        recordId: caseId,
        actionName: 'view'
      }
    });

}
```

```
<!--aura.cmp-->
    <lightning:messageChannel type="globalApiChannel__c"
                              onMessage="{!c.handleUtilityMessage}"
                              scope="APPLICATION"
    />
```

```
// auraController.js
    var action = event.getParam('action');
    var params = event.getParam('params');
    if (action === 'open-subtab') {
         // do your thing
    }
```

Comment: FYI cannot include an Aura Component inside a Lightning Web Component ([reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.interop_aura_composition)), so the hidden Aura Component inside a Lightning Web Component won't work. This solution I believe will require using an Aura Utility Bar component.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/use_config_for_utility_bar

Comment: It's interesting how generally bad the "new" Salesforce tech is. The most basic actions are not implemented

Comment: LWC is much comfortable to build with, while Aura has some additional API due to Locker Service limitation for example

Comment: LWCs are one step forward and five steps back. They're built on web components which all other web ecosystems have abandoned as bad practice. They force a poor development experience with limited functionality and a half baked module system. The template system and error handling is sub par. It's still about 15 years behind modern development practices.

Comment: @ytiq what do u mean by "you can also use hidden Utility Component"? Can be added an Utility bar component by not being visible in the Utility Bar? How can be done that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: from what I remember when you add Utility Component (to utility bar) there is checkbox (something like "Service Component") and it'll make this component shared for the whole app, but it won't be displayed in Utility Bar

Comment: @ytiq I checked, but I don't see that option when adding an aura cmp to Utility Bar of a Console app.

Comment: sorry for the delay. Here is the link https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:backgroundUtilityItem/documentation

Answer (score 3):

There is currently a GitHub Repo which I created that allows you to do this https://github.com/Pexlify/Console-Api-For-LWCs. You simply need to deploy this to your org and place the Aura component on any page which then allows you to simply call the console functions eg.

```javascript
import {openSubtabUrl} from 'c/consoleUtils';
import { MessageContext } from 'lightning/messageService';

@wire(MessageContext)messageContext

function example(){
   openSubtabUrl(this , 'https://example.com',true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Try this solution](https://mtr-design.com/news/salesforce-mini-how-to-open-a-subtab-in-console-from-lightning-web-component).

In The section **Solution #2**, you can see how to invoke workSpaceApi in LWC (you may need to modify some parameters, for example in my case i needed to close the current tab, so instead of using the parameter **parentTabId**, i changed it to **tabId**

Comment: That actually worked!! Do you know how the workspace invoking happening with custom event?